# how to use old endpoint name in sagemaker for same model configuration used before

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have encounterd a problem on creating sagemaker endpoint using the name that
was used in an endpoint that has been removed.

Is there time limit of the name being hold in the server after removing? or I can remove all the used name on old removed endpoints so that we can reuse those names?

I am quite new to aws development, so maybe missing something from the best practice on aws, any advice will be grateful on this issue. because creating new name every time updating the endpoints is a bit troublesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint has been deleted then you should be able to create a new endpoint with the same name. If you are still running into the issues it's also just simple to use something like the time library to automatically create a new endpoint name, look at the following code for reference:

```
#Step 3: EP Creation
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime

endpoint_name = "sklearn-local-ep" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
create_endpoint_response = client.create_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    EndpointConfigName=sklearn_epc_name,
)
print("Endpoint Arn: " + create_endpoint_response["EndpointArn"])
```